# Have loop repeat after invalid entry

Tags: loops, while-loop

All calculating is fine. I run into a problem when I get an invalid entry and the user enters a new positive integer. It doesn't start the loop over again. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start;
    int i;
    double squareRoot;

    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
    start = in.nextInt();

        if (start > 0){
        do {

            squareRoot = Math.sqrt(start);
            start--;
            System.out.printf("%.4f", squareRoot);
            System.out.println();
        }
        while (start >= 0);
        }

    else {
            System.out.println("The number you entered is not a postive integer.");
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than zero: ");
            start = in.nextInt();
            }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to go over the same steps over and over, you need a loop. So add a while loop with a simple condition and get it going over and over.

Here is a sample code. I had to give an option to quit, so took -1 as the cue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int start;
int i;
double squareRoot;


System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
boolean quit = false;
while (!quit) {
    System.out.println("Enter the integer");    
start = in.nextInt();    
    if (start > 0){
    do {

        squareRoot = Math.sqrt(start);
        start--;
        System.out.printf("%.4f", squareRoot);
        System.out.println();

    }
    while (start >= 0);
    }
else if (start == -1) {
   quit = true;
}
else {
        System.out.println("The number you entered is not a postive integer.");
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than zero: ");
}
}
}

}
```